# How to uninstall the resource of dependency chart when I uninstall the main chart Release?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, statefulset

Currently, I am using helm 3 , dependency chart to deploy a bitnami/postgresql statefulset with a nodeJS application,

however, the postgresql statefulset is still there when I uninstall the release.

now, I have to delete the statefulset and its resource (service, secret) one by one.

I am using `helm uninstall <release> -n <namespace>` to uninstall the nodejs release,

I check with the helm offical website and google search, its didnt mention lot about dependency chart uninstallation.

is there any command can uninstall the statefulset clearly? or even uninstall together with the application release?

Comment: The StatefulSet in the dependency chart should get cleaned up on its own (I do this somewhat routinely).  A PersistentVolumeClaim will get left behind but that's somewhat by design.